# Any way to include a new line in a field's default value?

Tags: custom-field, default-value

I would like to default some JSON including new lines:

```
[{
    "text": [...]
}]
```

in a LongTextArea field:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomField xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <defaultValue>&#39;[{&#10;"types": [...]&#10;}]&#39;</defaultValue>
    <fullName>AcknowledgmentJson__c</fullName>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>Acknowledgment JSON</label>
    <length>131072</length>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
    <type>LongTextArea</type>
    <visibleLines>10</visibleLines>
</CustomField>
```

but that markup will not deploy returning the error:

> Syntax error.  Missing '

as the new line `&#39;` is being immediately interpreted.

is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `& BR() &`? Just going off some older discussions [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000096thIAA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a great discussion [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000096thIAA) that outlines how to do it and some of the drawbacks

The short answer is to concatenate the BR() function in your default text where you want a break.

However there are some caveats that you'll want to read about in the above discussion (ex. the field value may not display correctly in Process Builder)